# Как сделать так, чтобы данная верстка выглядела одинаково как в Chrome, так и в IE 11?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer, кроссбраузерность

ВОПРОС 1

Есть такой код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Flex</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
  .top-menu {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    padding-left: 0;
    display: flex;
  }
  .top-menu__item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 18px;
  }
  .top-menu__item:nth-last-of-type(n+2) {
    border-right: 1px solid #96be4e;
  }
  .top-menu__link {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
</style>
<ul class="top-menu">
  <li class="top-menu__item">
    <a href="#" class="top-menu__link">Пункт 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="top-menu__item">
    <a href="#" class="top-menu__link">Пункт 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="top-menu__item">
    <a href="#" class="top-menu__link">Пункт 3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="top-menu__item">
    <a href="#" class="top-menu__link">Пункт-4</a>
  </li>
  <li class="top-menu__item">
    <a href="#" class="top-menu__link">Пункт-5</a>
  </li>
  <li class="top-menu__item">
    <a href="#" class="top-menu__link">Пункт-6</a>
  </li>
  <li class="top-menu__item">
    <a href="#" class="top-menu__link">Пункт 7 с каким-то текстом "какой-то текст"</a>
  </li>
  <li class="top-menu__item">
    <a href="#" class="top-menu__link">Пункт 8 тоже с текстом "какой-то текст"</a>
  </li>
  <li class="top-menu__item">
    <a href="#" class="top-menu__link">Пункт 9</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Он по-разному отображается в Chrome и в IE 11. Прикладываю скриншот. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ВОПРОС 2

Если я задам для блока `.top-menu__item` значение `flex-basis: 0;`, то в Chrome и IE будут разные результаты. Прикладываю скриншот.

Как сделать так, чтобы в IE отображение было таким же, как в Chrome? На flex'ах, а не на float'ах или inline'ах. Меня интересует исправление бага, а не изменение верстки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вещь может быть в display'ах. Эксплорер некоторые display воспринимает иначе. Кроме того, в CSS можно задать отдельные стили для разных браузеров (движков)

Comment: Используй префиксы [выбирай режимы](https://autoprefixer.github.io/ru/)

Comment: @SergeiDimitriev, какой режим нужно выбрать, чтобы мой код работал в IE также, как в Chrome?